# Misplaced glyphicons on angular-schema-form

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-schema-form

My angular schema form misplaces the inline glyphicons, they are shown on the upper right corner of the page instead:
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZpwS.png)

This app was built with yeoman, using generator-angular.

html:

```
<div class="login-container">
  <form name="myForm"
        sf-schema="schema"
        sf-form="form"
        sf-model="model"
        ng-submit="onSubmit(myForm)"></form>
</div>
```

ts:

```
angular.module('playgroundApp')
.controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.schema = {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Types",
    "properties": {
      "string": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 3
      },
      "integer": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "number": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "boolean": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "number"
    ]
  };

  $scope.form = [
    "*",
    {
      "type": "submit",
      "title": "OK"
    }
  ];

  $scope.model = {};

  $scope.onSubmit = function(form) {
    // First we broadcast an event so all fields validate themselves
    $scope.$broadcast('schemaFormValidate');

    // Then we check if the form is valid
    if (form.$valid) {
      // ... do whatever you need to do with your data.
    }
  }
}]);
```

I tried to search for conflicts between directives, unfortunately I couldn't reproduce the behaviour in a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pysYtTieMF0XUhXZ1uzU?p=preview).

bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "playground",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.3.0",
    "angular-ui-grid": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "ngstorage": "~0.3.9",
    "angular-ui-layout": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.14.3",
    "moment": "~2.10.6",
    "lodash": "~3.10.1",
    "angular-wizard": "~0.5.5",
    "ui-select": "angular-ui-select#~0.16.0",
    "select2": "~3.4.5",
    "angular-flash-alert": "~2.2.5",
    "angular-gantt": "^1.2.13",
    "angular-strap": "^2.3.7",
    "angular-schema-form": "~0.8.13",
    "angular-ui-tree": "~2.15.0",
    "components-font-awesome": "~4.6.1",
    "woodman": "~1.1.0",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "~1.0.3",
    "angular-picklist": "*",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.11.4",
    "angular-schema-form-bootstrap": "~0.2.0",
    "angular-schema-form-datepicker": "~0.4.0",
    "jquery": "~3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0",
    "ui-select": "angular-ui-select#~0.16.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "playgroundApp",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "lodash": "~3.10.1",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Update: Ignored this problem for 4 months. Facing it today I installed the latest versions of angular-schema-form and **angular-schema-form-bootstrap** and the problems were gone.

Comment: Right click and inspect element in F12 dev tools to see if any issues with the css?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that still has problems with those icons, is possible to disable them adding to each field in the form definition: `'feedback': false` as stated in the docs [here](https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/development/docs/index.md#standard-options).

Maybe not the best solution, but will help if you can live without the icons.